# The position of the word "with"

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

> We have no choice but to go on with our lives in the present, pushing
> into that tiny little bit of the future that our “now” slides into,
> without thinking about any of the things you’re saying—not because
> they aren’t worth thinking about (it would be wonderful if we could)
> but because we have no way of thinking about them, nothing to think
> about them **with**.”

Ultimate questions, Bryan Magee

Why were the word "with" placed in the end of the sentence. What is the role of it?

Answer (score 2):

You have a relative clause that could be written thus:

> we have . . . nothing **with which to think about them**

In a clause like this one, it is perfectly normal to postpone the preposition ("with") and delete the relative pronoun ("which"):

> we have . . . nothing **to think about them with**

You may be interested in the following:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preposition_stranding (see the example sentence "this is the book I told you about")
- [A question on relative clause](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/40324/a-question-on-relative-clause) (see example sentence #2)
- [Who / whom : The guests whom we were talking about have come are my brothers-in-law](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/139754/who-whom-the-guests-whom-we-were-talking-about-have-come-are-my-brothers-in/139777#139777) (Gary Botnovcan's answer)

Answer (score 2):

The word "with" is a preposition. It has many uses. See [Cambridge on "with"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/with)

One meaning is "using".

> We use with to refer to what we use to do something:

> - They opened the package with a knife.

> - I’ll tie it with some tape to keep it closed.

> - He cleaned the table with a cloth he found in the kitchen

From this meaning one might formulate the phrase:

> ... we have nothing with which to think about.

This includes a relative clause, headed by "which:.  That clause can be reduced and inverted, resulting in:

> ... we have nothing to think about them with.

Thus "with" in this usage is a preposition indicating a thing to be used for a purpose. In this case, the unspecified thing (that the author says we do not have) to be used to "think about them".